RESTEASY000100: Failed executing POST: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Getting intermittent errors on Jboss 5 for POST requests, most requests go through only some run into error.
2024-09-10 11:46:15,389 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] RESTEASY000100: Failed executing POST /rest/demo
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:201)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:160)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:362)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:507)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:224)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory._createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:785)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:561)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:405)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:109)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168)
        ... 32 more

Thought it was due to conflict between Jackson dependencies. Can restlet affect anything for resteasy? Or any directions that can help track what is wrong?
